# MSTest Request for principal permission failed

Tags: security, attributes, mstest, using, genericprincipal

I've looked at the very good content at this thread and it hasn't solved my problem. [MSTEST PrincipalPermission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106163/mstest-principalpermission)

My class:

```
public class SecurityUsingAttributes
{
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "SomeRole")]
    public int MyMethod1()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

My test:

```
[TestClass]
public class SecurityUsingAttributesTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        IIdentity identity = new GenericIdentity(@"MyDomain\MyName");
        string[] roles = new string[] { "SomeRole"};

        IPrincipal genericPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);


        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = genericPrincipal;

        SecurityUsingAttributes target = new SecurityUsingAttributes();

        Assert.IsTrue(5 == target.MyMethod1());
    }
}
```

This works now.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the assignment for CurrentPrincipal. The above code works now.